# Is there any good jQuery plugin for datatable or datagrid?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, datagrid

We are developing an Java at back-end appliation. In the front-end we want to display a lot of datagrid. Is there any good jQuery plugin for datatable or datagrid?

We are using this https://datatables.net/ plugin now. But we need to write all templates in the javascript. Is there any better plugin that we can write some html templates and append data via javascript.

Or even better, is there any JSP or JSF based datagrid can do Ajax pagination and sorting?

Thanks

Comment: Did you checkout the jqGrid by tirend?

Comment: have you checked jqgrid...????

Comment: I have checked the jqGrid, but I can't find the place where I can put a html table template. The plugin I want to is a html template based and javascript dynamic appends data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this one could help you ?

FuelUX Datagrid

http://exacttarget.github.io/fuelux/#datagrid

Comment: It looks good. Do you have more detail example to explain the datagrid. Such as the format of datasoure should be.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bdeanet/WMHcu/